# Lua 'end' expected (to close 'if' at line 11) near 'until'

Tags: lua

A function I'm using gives me the `'end' expected (to close 'if' at line 11) near 'until'` error when I run it, but I checked and I'm not missing a `'end'` in the entire program. Also, I'm not using return or some other command like that (That I'm aware of)

```
function sell_item(item, soldfor)
  items_found = 0
  for i, v in pairs(inv) do
      if v == item then
          items_found = items_found + 1
      end
  end
  if items_found ~= 0 then
      items_destroyed = 0
      until items_destroyed == 1 do
          for i, v in pairs(inv) do
              if v == item then
                  pop_inv(item)
                  items_destroyed = 1
                  io.write(item .. " sold for " .. soldfor .. " coins")
                  count = 0
                  while count ~= soldfor do
                      table.insert(money, "coin")
                      count = count + 1
                  end
                  count = 0
              end
          end
          items_destroyed = 0
      end
  elseif items_found == 0 then
      io.write("You do not have this item")
  end
end
```

Comment: your `if` is missing a `then`.

Comment: @daurnimator Forgot to update that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `until` is the second half of the `repeat - until` loop, and you have written it without a preceding repeat statement. Replace `until` with `while` and it should run fine, as it appears you are wanting to have a loop with the test at the beginning of the loop, which is a `while` loop. An `until` loop has the test at the end.

Comment: Cleared up the problem, been slaving for 3 hours, thanks!